# How to use Behat/Mink to fill out a test Stripe checkout form?

Tags: stripe-payments, e2e-testing, behat, mink

I'm trying to test my checkout flow that integrates Drupal 9 with Stripe checkout.

I use Behat for testing Drupal, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on the Stripe checkout page.

An example of the Stripe checkout page I am trying to work with can be accessed by going to [the Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) and clicking the **Checkout** button.

Here's my behat step:

```
  /**
   * Enter a Stripe Visa credit card.
   *
   * @Then I fill in a valid card on Stripe
   */
  public function fillInCardOnStripe(): void {
    $selector_card_number = 'cardNumber';
    $selector_card_expiry = 'cardExpiry';
    $selector_cvc = 'cardCVC';
    $selector_billing_name = 'billingName';

    $test_card_number = '4242424242424242';
    $test_card_expiry = '11/25';
    $test_cvc = '123';
    $test_billing_name = 'Marcus Aurelius';

    $this->assertEnterField($selector_card_number, $test_card_number);
    $this->assertEnterField($selector_card_expiry, $test_card_expiry);
    $this->assertEnterField($selector_cvc, $test_cvc);
    $this->assertEnterField($selector_billing_name, $test_billing_name);
  }
```

However, when my test navigates to the Stripe checkout page, I get the following error:

```
And I fill in a valid card on Stripe                                                                                # DrupalMinkContext::fillInCardOnStripe()
  Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "cardNumber" not found.
```

I don't understand why because when I open the browser dev tools, the `name` of the Stripe card number input element is `cardNumber`.

How can I fill out the card number fields on the Stripe checkout page?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes forms can obfuscate inputs to prevent automated entry - payment forms are an excellent example of this.  there are multiple solutions to this problem:

1. Use selenium more directly.  Mink is a wrapper for the selenium functions to find inputs and type into them - in this case you'll need to find the form field with some custom CSS selector and then to type... so either use different Mink functions or selenium functions to access/fill the form input.
2. As above but using selenium to use JavaScript directly to update the input value.
3. As above but use [keyboard navigation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/) to "tab" into the field and then type.
4. As above but using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/) to send keys to that window (i.e. behat writes a script from a template and shell execs it during step).  Note I have used this for windows applications that are part of the scenario I'm testing.  Provided this is a windows problem.